# ListBox item windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to resize item in ListBox from C#? I can do `ListBox.Height = 100;` but I don't know how to resize items in ListBox. Help me, please.

I need to change the size of items in listBox and their number using the ManipulationDelta method.

Main xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="tileList"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        ManipulationCompleted="tileList_ManipulationCompleted"
        ManipulationDelta="tileList_ManipulationDelta">

    <ListBox.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </ListBox.RenderTransform>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:HubTile x:Name="hubMain"
                            Title="{Binding Title}"
                            Margin="3"
                            DisplayNotification="{Binding DisplayNotification}"
                            GroupTag="{Binding GroupTag}"
                            Message="{Binding Message}"
                            Notification="{Binding Notification}"
                            Size="Medium"
                            Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

and C# code:

private void tileList_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
    {

        double newWidth = 0.0, newHieght = 0.0;

        foreach (tileList lv in tileList.Items)
        {
            lv.Height = 10;
        }
    }
}

private void tileList_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    m_Zoom = 200 / 10;
}

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always change the ItemTemplate of your ListBox inside the Xaml page

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Height="200" Width="200" /> //This is just an example you can use any control
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Items of the Listbox and set the individual height for them like this,

```
 foreach (ListBoxItem lv in YourListbox.Items)
        {
            lv.Height = 10;
        }
```

Comment: private void tileList_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
    {

        double newWidth=0.0, newHieght=0.0;

            foreach (ListBoxItem lv in tileList.Items)
            {
                lv.Height = 10;
            }
    }
}

private void tileList_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    m_Zoom = 200 / 10;
}

Comment: Thanks. but why showing exception (An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in apps123.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'apps123.TileItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem'.)

Comment: replace with this foreach (TileItem in YourListbox.Items)

Comment: error: Erro 'apps123.MainPage.tileList' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: <ListBox x:Name="tileList"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="5"
        ManipulationCompleted="tileList_ManipulationCompleted"
        ManipulationDelta="tileList_ManipulationDelta">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>

Comment: </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:HubTile Title="{Binding Title}"
                            Margin="3"
                            DisplayNotification="{Binding DisplayNotification}"
                            GroupTag="{Binding GroupTag}"
                            Message="{Binding Message}"
                            Notification="{Binding Notification}"
                            Size="Medium"
                            Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>